# CMake Version setting: Am I suppose to set the `C++` version in my project-root `CMakeLists.txt` file using CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD, or `CXX_STANDARD`?

Tags: cmake

This is probably a dumb question. If its a duplicate I couldn't find it.

I am pretty new to CMake, I was first introduced to it via **JetBrains IDE: CLion**. I moved to VSCode, because I don't feel as comfortable, or as well equipped in any other environment, as I do in VSCode. Unfortunately building projects is generally easier in a true IDE, especially in VS2022. In VSCode I have to configure most stuff myself, but in truth, I learn way more doing that way, so I don't mind. So I usually set the version of C++ I am using via the ***project-root:*** **`CMakeLists.txt`**. Just now when I went to start a new project though I noticed something that popped up from Intellisense/Intellicode, there were two options I could choose:

---

1. ##### `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD <ver>`
2. ##### `CXX_STANDARD <ver>`

---

I have used, `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17`, for about a year and a half, and never seen the version of the setting that isn't prepended with *"CMAKE_"*. When I google it, I just find results for the *CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD* setting, which isn't surprising considering there syntax is nearly identical.

Further more, I tried them both, and I didn't notice a difference, but I don't really notice a difference when I don't add the configuration anyways. I was just wondering if what the difference is, if any, so I know which to use, and more importantly why to use it.

---

###### *Below is an img that shows the `C_CPP Microsoft IntelliSense` extension's suggestions in V.S. Code.*

[image]

---

##### NOTE:

The line: ***`set(CXX_STANDARD)`***
is formatted wrong, it should have looked like this instead:
***`set(CXX_STANDARD 17)`***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use either of `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` and `CXX_STANDARD`, but note that they are **different entities**:

1. [CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html) is a **variable**, so it can be set with `set` command:

   ```
   set(CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED 17)
   ```

   This setting would affect on **all** executable/library targets **created after** it.
2. [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) is a **target property**, so it can be set with `set_property` or `set_target_properties` commands:

   ```
   set_property(TARGET my_target PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
   ```

   This setting should be performed **after creating** the target `my_target` and affects only on the given target.

---

Attempt to set a property like a variable:

```
set(CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

is simply **wrong**: It sets a **variable** `CXX_STANDARD`, and this variable is **never used** by CMake.

Comment: Your absolutely right, thats a mistake on my part.

Comment: I was going to fix my answer, but really there doesn't need to be two. I appreciate you taking the time to correct my mistake, and to author an answer. I originally asked this question not to answer it, but to know why there were two settings so similar. I also wanted to make sure anyone else who wondered, got an answer.